# three.js - How to export MultiMaterial?

Tags: three.js

This is a snippet of my code -

```
materialArray=[];
materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:frontCounterTexture}));
materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:frontCounterTexture}));
materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:frontCounterTexture}));
materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:blackTexture}));
materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:blackTexture}));
materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:blackTexture}));

frontCounterMaterial=new THREE.MultiMaterial(materialArray);
frontCounter.material=frontCounterMaterial;
```

The scene gets rendered properly using the editor (threejs/editor), however export doesn't work.
When I do the following -

```
frontCounter.toJSON()
```

I get the following -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textures' of undefined(…)
```

I traced it back to -

```
THREE.Texture.toJSON:
if ( meta.textures[ this.uuid ] !== undefined ) {

        return meta.textures[ this.uuid ];

    }
```

I do not understand how to fix this, that is export a Mesh with MultiMaterial applied to it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The PR on github suggests that it currently works with MeshPhongMaterial https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/6509, I suggest trying that instead of MeshBasicMaterial.